# How to turn numeric value into currency in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, salesforce, rounding, currency

I am new to BigQuery and am trying to convert numeric values (from Salesforce) to currency (preferably dollar value).

Very basically, what I have currently is:

```
SELECT salesforce.Name,
       ROUND(salesforce.Amount,2) as Amount 

FROM table.salesforce
```

Which obviously only rounds the value to two decimal places.

Comment: Hi, "currency" isn't a data type in BigQuery - what are you trying to achieve? If you want to store these values as a string with a dollar sign in front of them you can do something like CONCAT("$", CAST(salesforce.Amount AS STRING)) - but you will not be able to do any calculations such as SUM on string values. What is the problem with rounding to two decimal places as shown in your question? Is it the loss of accuracy due to rounding? I'd recommend leaving your values as numeric in BigQuery and doing what is essentially display formatting in your data vizualisation or reporting tools.

Comment: Thank you - I formatted the gsheet it displays into, but thought it would just be neater to have the currency values coming from the report itself. I used the FORMAT/CONCAT approach and it works fine for what I need. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding your question about how to convert a numeric value to currency value in BigQuery, I would advise you to use the ***FORMAT()*** and ***CONCAT()*** built-in functions.

I see that in your question you mentioned you want to round the numeric values to the second decimal place, you can do that using ***FORMAT()***, you can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format). In addition, to use the "$" sign, you can use [CONCAT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#concat). Below is an example where I used some dummy data to exemplify what I explained:

```
  WITH
  data AS (
  SELECT
    20.21 AS num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    99999999.12 AS num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    12345 AS num )
  SELECT
  CONCAT('$ ',FORMAT("%'.2f", num)) AS new_num
  FROM
  data
```

And the output:

[image]

Notice that in the ***FORMAT()*** function I used *"%'.2f"*, which rounds the number to the second decimal place. You can find more information about the meaning of each letter/number in the expression using the following [guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#supported_format_specifiers).

As a bonus information, the currency values are formatted in a way that the dot **"."** is a decimal separator and the comma **","** is a grouping separator. You can switch that using regex expressions with [REGEX_REPLACE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace) and [REPLACE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#replace) functions. If that is the case, just let me know so I can help.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's so helpful.

Comment: @olivia,I am glad I could help. I would appreciate if you could upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the method that I use:

`CAST(YourNumber AS STRING FORMAT '$999,999')`

With decimal points:

`CAST(YourNumber AS STRING FORMAT '$999,999.00')`