# Big Query Error When Using CAST and determining decimals

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have linked a Big Query Project to my Google Ads Account. Within that, we have a campaignBasicStats table.

I want to pull the cost of a campaign from my Google Ads account into a big query workspace to apply some additional logic.

The cost column is coming through as an INTEGER and is described like this:
INTEGER NULLABLE
The sum of your cost-per-click (CPC) and cost-per-thousand impressions (CPM) costs during this period. Values can be one of: a) a money amount in micros, b) "auto: x" or "auto" if this field is a bid and AdWords is automatically setting the bid via the chosen bidding strategy, or c) "--" if this field is a bid and no bid applies to the row.

If I query the table, the cost returns in this value: Example:
2590000.0
965145.0

In Google Ads, the two costs for these campaigns are £25.90 and £96.51

So I have this code in my Big Query Workspace.

```
SELECT CAST(Cost AS FLOAT64)
FROM `db_table`
WHERE COST > 0
LIMIT 1000
```

The column returns these numbers:

```
2590000.0
965145.0
```

However, As I need the numbers to be a currency for example the first return 2590000.0 should be 25.90 and the second one should be 96.51

I changed my code to this:

```
SELECT CAST(Cost AS FLOAT64(4,2))
FROM `db_table`
WHERE COST > 0
LIMIT 1000
```

And now I get this error:

> FLOAT64 does not support type parameters at [1:28]

Is there something I'm missing? how do I convert to decimal point and specify where I want the decimal point to be in BQ?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn numeric value into currency in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272446/how-to-turn-numeric-value-into-currency-in-bigquery)

Comment: https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/

Comment: This question needs clarification:

1. What data type is Cost in your source?

2. By what logic does 2590000.0 become 25.90 but 965145.0 becomes 96.51? Are we just trying to grab the first 4 digits?

3. Are you only looking for a formatted result that you'd get from something like FORMAT("%.*f",2,CAST(Cost AS FLOAT64) + .0001) or do you need rounding?


Please flesh these details out in your question and I'm happy to help you with an answer specific to your issue.

Comment: Hi All, I tried to use the link in the first comment - and it didn't work, apologies.

Comment: Hi Brad, 
So, the original number is a INTEGER and I'm pulling this data from Google Ads, so within the Google Ad platform, on that day, for that campaign I've spent 25.90 but in BiGQuery it is coming out at 2590000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using a Google Ads Data Transfer operation as detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer).

In this case, it's important to note the Description of the Cost column in p_CampaignBasicStats:

> The sum of your cost-per-click (CPC) and cost-per-thousand impressions
> (CPM) costs during this period. Values can be one of: **a) a money
> amount in micros**, b) "auto: x" or "auto" if this field is a bid and
> AdWords is automatically setting the bid via the chosen bidding
> strategy, or c) "--" if this field is a bid and no bid applies to the
> row.

1 micro is 1-millionth of the fundamental currency. Thus, we need to transform this amount as such: `cost / 1000000`

Then, we simply need to ROUND to get the appropriate unit. *If you prefer to always round up, see my answer regarding the correct way to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73444412/3907405).*

First, we'll set up an example table with the example values you've given:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE ex_db_table ( Cost INTEGER );

INSERT INTO
  ex_db_table
VALUES
  ( 2590000 );

INSERT INTO
  ex_db_table
VALUES
  ( 965145 );
```

Then we'll select the data in your preferred unit:

```
SELECT
  ROUND(Cost / 1000000, 2) as currency_cost
FROM
  ex_db_table;
```

Of note, your math in your question is incorrect here as the actual values of your Cost examples equate to 2.59 and 0.97.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - The above code spits out this error: Query error: Temporary tables may not be qualified at [1:19]

Apologies for the lack of information - i will re-write the question.

Comment: I've updated my question with some more detail - hope that helps?

Comment: @Ian, I've updated my answer based on your update and tried to add some clarity. Ultimately, the SELECT statement remains the same so you should try that on your data. The error you received is likely because you already had a table named `db_table` in your active dataset (which would make sense based on your posted example). I changed my example table name to `ex_db_table` so all the language I've provided should now run. However, I suggest you just try running the DQL with your table name and see if you get the intended result. Please let me know if I can lend more clarity.

Comment: There is one confounding issue in your use case here, though. If your cost for an ad goes up to 100+, this approach would no longer work as it's only looking at the first two characters. I'm confused as to why google ads is producing this data as an integer with unpredictable length. Are you sure the figures aren't always 6 digits, for example?

Comment: I agree it's very odd, for cost that is over £100, it still returns in an integer. For example, on the 14th Aug, we spent £321.43 in Google Ads, but in the Big Query report, it returns as 321430000

Comment: The code above works, but how do I do this on a larger scale when the data is held in a table (table name - `my-bq-project1.Client_Name_Ads.p_CampaignBasicStats_4271247123`

Comment: A couple of things: 1. I'm going to go look at my personal ads account to see how it exports cost. Maybe I can get a better handle on your use case. 2. If you wanted to use this code (which I don't really advise for your use case), just change the table name in the FROM clause to the table name you've given above.

Comment: Can you tell me which report from ads you're exporting?

Comment: I connected my Google Ads account to a Big Query project. so the table is p_CampaignBasicStats

Comment: OK! Now I understand. Please see my edited answer which I believe should resolve all your concerns. If you have additional questions, please don't hesitate to ask.